# Tailwindcss @apply directive not working in external file

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwindCSS over the CDN. It's a basic project that I want to create includes only few pages. But I have some components that has same UI.

I loaded the tailwind with this script tag. `<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>`

If I use `@apply` directive within the HTML file it's working. Like this;

```
<style type="text/tailwindcss">
        .package {
            @apply
            w-72
            p-5
            bg-white
            rounded-xl
            border
            drop-shadow-2xl
        }
    </style>
```

But I want to move this definition into the `main.css` file which I externally loaded. All the files are pure CSS and HTML. Is it possible to use it in that way ?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Multiple Plan</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script src="tailwind.config.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
    <!-- I want to move that below part into main.css file -->
    <style type="text/tailwindcss">
        .package {
            @apply
            w-72
            p-5
            bg-white
            rounded-xl
            border
            drop-shadow-2xl
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex items-end justify-center gap-8">
      <div id="pack1" class="package">
            <div class="title">
                <h4>Enterprise Plan</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                £350 <small>/ month</small>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Unlimited Couriers</li>
                <li>PDF Supported label formats</li>
                <li>Intelligent Tracking Included**</li>
                <li>Intelligent Address Formatting</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="/" class="get-started-button">
                Get Started
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="package">
            <div class="title">
                <h4>XXL Plan</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                £350 <small>/ month</small>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Unlimited Couriers</li>
                <li>PDF Supported label formats</li>
                <li>Intelligent Tracking Included**</li>
                <li>Intelligent Address Formatting</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="/" class="get-started-button">
                Get Started
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the file where you import you import your tailwindcss base,component and layers, use @layer components { your custom css }

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atif0075/Vue-Tailwind-Firebase-Recipe-App/master/src/index.css like this

Comment: Thanks @ChAtif. I already tried your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share more details, like code inside GitHub repo

Comment: Hi @ChAtif, I updated my question with sample code. It's a concept page for a company, therefore I can share the part of I'm having issue. If you copy/paste my sample code, you'll see tailwind will work but once you move .package class into main css file, it won't work.

Comment: In my opinion, it will not work until you install tailwindcss as a package instead of using CDN(also it is not recommended). After installation it will work like https://play.tailwindcss.com/GyoMxDCdW7?file=css

Comment: @ChAtif I'm also at the same point. Kind of usage doesn't work with CDN implementation. But I'm not able to create npm project for this app. Whatever, thanks for your communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired results this way

```css
 <style type="text/tailwindcss">
    @layer utilities {
      .package {
            @apply
            w-72
            p-5
            bg-white
            rounded-xl
            border
            drop-shadow-2xl
        }
    }
  </style>
```

Add this style tag under in your head tag and customise it according to your needs.

It is mentioned in official documents by tailwindcss at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but it's already been applied and working like that. Please check the question again.